How can Kafka consumer can deserialize dto object sent by producer?
I am using spring to send message to kafka consumer.
this.kafkaTemplate.send(applicationProperties.getKafka().getTopics().getNoticeGenerationEventsTopic(),
                            japserName, noticeEventDTO);

But kafka is not able to deserialize noticeEventDTO dto as it doesn't know about this DTO. It is from sender microservice.
How I can make kafka aware about this class So it can deserialize the class?
I am getting following error:
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.xyz.abc.registration.service.dto.NoticeEventDTO]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:137)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.determineJavaType(JsonMessageConverter.java:135)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.extractAndConvertValue(JsonMessageConverter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.toMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:193)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:346)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2857)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.xyz.registration.service.dto.NoticeEventDTO
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:121)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:304)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:133)
    ... 20 common frames omitted

Class not found is fully qualified name of producer dto class.

The reason for the error is that the com.abc.xyz.registration.service.dto.NoticeEventDTO class is not in your classpath.

Kafka doesn't need to be aware. It accepts bytes, not deserializes the event.
The consumer needs to either copy the same models from the produced code base, or the producer app needs to publish a Maven dependency for the consumer to use

Even if I copy the same model, fully qualified name would be different

Why can't you use the same package structure for just those classes? That's how maven external dependencies would be setup as well. You can use a separate maven module as well (or Gradle if you use that)

Looks like you are using JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer, which I believe assumes the same classes are available on both the consumer and producer side (I think the class name is written into the headers of the Kafka message, which are used when you deserialize).
Now because the KafkaTemplate only has generics, without additional configuration, all that's available when deserializing, is the class name in the header and because that's not-found, you get the exception you're seeing.
Read the Spring Docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#json-serde) for more options on how to configure the serialization/deserialization when using Kafka with Spring.
Which solution you choose is going to be specific to your use-case.

Type Mappings work, though

@OneCricketeer yeah, there's lot of options; I think the looser the coupling the better, so giving the types common names and then mapping classes in the consumer to those names would certainly work.
